# What functions can be applied to rvalues?

Tags: c++

I saw this:

```
std::tie(iter, inserted) = set_of_s.insert(value);
```

from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie

`std::tie` should return a rvalue tuple, but an assignment operator is then applied to it.  How this works? I thought assignment operators can only apply to lvalue?

Comment: By definition `std::tie` returns an object (not even reference to it) that has `operator=()` defined. And that operator is called. As usual. Where do you see the problem?

Comment: @c-smile I am just really confused cuz opetator=() returns a lvalue reference and theres no lvaue anywhere for it to return...

Comment: That assignment of yours is exactly this:

`{ std::tie temp(iter, inserted); temp.operator=(set_of_s.insert(value)); }`. As you see it is just a function call on temporary object,

Comment: @texasbruce: Value categories apply to expressions, not objects. Within the function, `*this` is an _lvalue_, even if the function was called on an _rvalue_; so it can return an _lvalue_ reference to that.

Comment: @MikeSeymour but isn't that a dangling reference then? cuz the rvlaue would be end-of-life after the statement?

Comment: @texasbruce: If you store the reference until after the temporary is destroyed at the end of the statement, then yes, it will be left dangling; so don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What functions can be applied to rvalues?

An *rvalue* can be

- passed as the `this` argument of a member function
- passed by value
- passed by `const` *lvalue* reference
- passed by *rvalue* reference.

It can't be passed by non-const *lvalue* reference.

> How this works?

The overloaded assignment operator is a member function, so can be called on an *rvalue*.

> I thought assignment operators can only apply to lvalue?

That's the case with built-in assignment operators. Overloaded operators are functions, and follow the same rules as functions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the built-in `=` operator must have an lvalue as its left operand. However, this isn't the built-in `=` operator, as much as it looks like it. Instead it's a call to the function `operator=` and is equivalent to:

```
std::tie(iter, inserted).operator=(set_of_s.insert(value));
```

The class member access operator `.` does not need its left operand to be an lvalue, so everything is okay.

Side note: don't confuse the value category of expressions with the lvalue/rvalue reference types. The assignment operator could very well have the name of an rvalue reference as its left operand, because the expression that is its name is an lvalue.

Comment: That is by definition *the* `=` operator for that type. It is just a member of the type, which is what enables this use.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Yeah, bad phrasing, I should fix it.

Comment: But assignment operator returns a lvalue reference. Where is the lvalue from?

Comment: @texasbruce It doesn't matter what the assignment operator returns. It's about what `std::tie(iter, inserted)` returns. That returns an object by value, which means that the expression in an rvalue. It's fine to use `.` to access a member of an rvalue.

Comment: and i know this is not "built-in" equal operator. That's why I said `what functions` can be applied.

Comment: How does it not matter? It returns a lvalue reference, and it has to come from somewhere right?

Comment: @texasbruce Sure, it returns an lvalue reference to `*this`, which is the `std::tuple` object you're applying it to. What's the problem with that?